# Use JUnit to test object using dependency injection

Tags: java, netbeans, dependency-injection, junit

I have a class which using dependency injection to load some plugins. Injection based on Java ServiceLoader with default class loader.

Problems appears during testing because I cant figure out how force NetBeans load META-INF/services for test cases and I always getting 'java.util.ServiceConfigurationError:.... provider not found'.

I know that it is not very easy to write tests for DI-bases classes but maybe you know right way?

Serg

Comment: I'm assuming that you know about how to mock out dependencies and that this doesn't apply to your question.  I tend to mock out most of my injected dependencies in unit tests.  Easymock++.

Comment: One of the reason for Dependency Injection is testability. You should easily be able to mock the dependencies in the object under test. Like Gray said, have a look at EasyMock, Mockito or any similar mocking frameworks.